# Tumblr navigation element listing posts chronologically?

Tags: navigation, tumblr, permalinks

I'd like to create a fixed `<div>` on the left margin of a Tumblr powered page.

It would appear on `/tagged/x` pages (which is how my content is categorised), and it would link to the last ten or so posts under that tag chronologically (backwards if possible).

The styling and fixing into the margin is all fine but I'm struggling to work out how to generate the list of permalinks, perhaps with the `{blocks}` that the Tumblr platform provides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use [Tumblr's API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) to retrieve a list of the last ten posts of a tag. You might consider the [first version](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1#api_read) of their API because you wouldn't need to register an application and use OAuth.

Comment: I take it this would have to be implemented with Javascript? So I take it that script can be embedded in the theme code under a <script> tag as other .js scripts can. How would I tunnel the output of the API request into the navigational element?